# Regex is not working

Tags: java, regex

Following is my program.

I was trying replace  `@`, `&`, `;`, and `.` with space ().

But I am unable to get the correct output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String REG_EXPR = "[!\"#$%&'()*+-./:;<=>?@\\^_{|}~`,.\\[\\]–]*";
        String Description="திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@;ஆனால் ஆனால் ";
        HashSet<String> line=new HashSet<String>();
        Scanner sc2 = null;
         sc2 = new Scanner(Description);
         while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
         Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
         boolean b;
         while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.next();                   
                String s1 = s.replaceAll(REG_EXPR, "");       
                s1=s1.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");

                System.out.println("s1 value"+s1);

               }  
             }
           }
```

output

```
s1 valueதிகழ்கிறதுஆனால்
s1 valueஆனால்
```

expected output

```
 s1 valueதிகழ்கிறது
 s1 valueஆனால்  
  s1 valueஆனால்
```

Comment: can you use english examples ?

Comment: Tamil Text only problem

Comment: What do you call a "special character" here?

Comment: I am not able to understand expected and actual output. Use english text instead of tamil.

Comment: See if my answer helps; I understand that what you call a "special character" is "anything which is not a letter, whatever the language).

Comment: @aelor there is not only English in life!

Comment: @user3382635 dude, its not about the language anyway, dont feel hurt , its just that are we splitting at the right places in the string you have provided or not

Comment: if i use english no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String REG_EXPR = "[!\"#$%&'()*+-./:;<=>?@\\^_{|}~`,.\\[\\]–]";
    String description="திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@;ஆனால் ஆனால் ";
    String s1 = description.replaceAll(REG_EXPR," ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s1);
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("s1 value " + scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Check it here http://ideone.com/omjhHM

Answer (score 0):

Try and do that:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsL}+");

// ...
final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(description);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: i got  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException

Comment: o/p is like த
கழ
க
றத
ஆன
ல
ஆன
ல

Comment: Yup, it looks like there are not only letters in your Tamil input. What else can there be?

Comment: திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@;ஆனால் come from server .how can i add space programatically'

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your scanner class processing

The first piece of string which you are getting is "திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@;ஆனால்" and it's doing the regex correctly and the expected out put is "திகழ்கிறதுஆனால்"

Give a space here "திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@; ஆனால்" and try,you will get the correct output.

try this,

final String REG_EXPR = "[!\"#$%&'()*+-./:;<=>?@\^_{|}~`,.\[\]–a-zA-Z0-9\\s]";

replace the while loop with below,

```
                  while (s2.hasNext()) {
                         String s = s2.next();                   
                         String []s1 = s.split(REG_EXPR);
                      for(int i=0 ;i<s1.length;i++ )
                         if(s1[i].length()>0)
                             System.out.println("s1 value"+s1[i]);

                        }
```

Comment: but திகழ்கிறது.@;@;@;@;ஆனால் this text comming from server

Answer (score -2):

Remember to escape regex-specific characters such as `*+?` to `\\*\\+\\?`. Otherwise these will be used to determine the length of the matching sample. I.e. `?` means `occurs zero or one times`, `+` means `one or more times`, `*` means `any times (zero, one or more)`.

Comment: No need to escape any of these inside a character class